# Remove query string from www/http redirect

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, url-rewriting

I have currently htaccess which redirects index.php?page=start to /start etc, and recently wanted to implement redirect with www to non-www with SSL. Now I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

It's all working decent except when I try to redirect from www or http in an innerpage. So in example.com/start, going from www and/or http, I get: https://example.com/start?page=start

The problem is the ?page=start , which I wanna remove. Is it possible to rewrite to remove it, when redirecting from http/www?

Comment: `non-www` to `www` and `http` => `https` Rules should be before internal ones. You need to change order of your Rules.

Comment: How do you mean? All `www` to `non-www` and `http to https `combinations are working fine, but it redirects from `http://example.com/start` (or the other combinations which should execute redirection) to `https://example.com/start` **?page=start** instead of just `https://example.com/start`

I've tried reordering but getting the same result

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, I've also checked with redirect checkers with shows the same result. I'm guessing the `{REQUEST_URI}` includes the query string for some reason, I've been researching how to redirect without the query string but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the flag `QSD (Query String Discard)` to the redirects, which stopped passing the query string.